# Multibib prints redundant references in two bibliographies when cite command is redefined

Tags: bibtex, citing, multibib, cite-package, springernature

I have a document where I have two bibliographies, defined using `multibib`. I am trying to change how in-line citations are displayed, but this causes `multibib` to print redundant references in both citations. The problem goes away when `cite` is not refined.

I am using the `nature.cls` document class.

The command that is causing multiple references to be printed in both bibliographies (and produced multiply defined reference warnings) is:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{\textsuperscript{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}}
\makeatother
```

How do I redefine `cite` as shown, and not have redundant entries in the two bibliographies?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{nature}

\usepackage{multibib}


\newcites{methods}{References (Methods):}

\renewcommand\citeform[1]{[#1]}


\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{\textsuperscript{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}}
\makeatother



\newcites{online}{Online References}

\begin{document}

\bigskip

\section*{Main}
\label{sec:main}

Some text \cite{RefA, RefB} and \citeonline{RefC}. More text \cite{RefA, RefB}. \\ \\

\bibliographystyle{naturemag}
\bibliography{references}

\bigskip

\section*{Methods}
\label{sec:methods}

Some text \cite{RefA, RefB} and \citeonline{RefC}. More text \cite{RefA, RefB}. \\ \\

\bibliographystyleonline{naturemag}
\bibliographyonline{references}

    
\end{document}
```